# how can I remove \r \n and \ from a string in perl

Tags: perl

I need to remove every \r \n and \ in that order from a big $string, how can I accomplish that?

Example string:

```
$string = '\/9jAAMAAAAB\r\nAAEAAABAAAD\/2'
```

need it to look like this:

```
$string = '/9jAAMAAAABAAEAAABAAAD/2'
```

Comment: if you shrunk the string to be as small as possible while still showing your use cases, it would make things easier

Comment: the assignment you show sets $string to have literal carriage return and newline characters where the \r and \n are; the backslashes before the forward slashes are ignored.  What does the string really look like to start with?  (e.g. show us the output of `use Data::Dumper; print Data::Dumper->new([$string])->Terse(1)->Useqq(1)->Dump()`)

Comment: Is the text a literal backslash character followed by a `n`, or is it an embedded `<NL>` character in the string?

Comment: a literal n, if i were to print $ string it would be exactly \/9jAAMAAAAB\r\nAAEAAABAAAD\/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
$new_string = $string =~ s/\\|\R//g;
print "$new_string";
```

Comment: This prints "2". `=~` has higher precedence than `=`.

Comment: @BluGeni: What is version of Perl do you use? \R is in Perl 5.10 or later.

You can use \\r|\\n instead.

Comment: @mob: Yeah, It exactly what I want. Substitution assigned to $string, then $string assigned to $new_string.

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$string = "something\\r\\n\\";
$string =~ s/(\\r)|(\\n)|(\\)//g;
print $string;

=> something
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = '\/9jAAMAAAAB\r\nAAEAAABAAAD\/2';
$string =~ s!\\[rn]?!!g;
print $string;
```

Output:

```
/9jAAMAAAABAAEAAABAAAD/2
```